# How to bind dictionary with containing list to grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dictionary

How to bind this dictionary to grid view -

```
   Dictionary<int, Actor> actors = new Dictionary<int, Actor>{
    {
        1,new Actor
        {
            ActorId = 1,
            ActorName= "Rajanikant",
            BirthDate =DateTime.Parse("12-12-1949"), 
            BirthPlace ="Bangalore", 
            Photo ="~/Images/1.jpg", 
            Movies = new List<string>{"Shivaji (2007)","Baba (2002)","ChaalBaaz (1989)"}
        }
    },                 
    {
        2,new Actor
        {
            ActorId = 2,
            ActorName= "Jennifer Aniston", 
            BirthDate =DateTime.Parse("11-2-1969"), 
            BirthPlace ="Sherman Oaks", 
            Photo ="~/Images/2.jpg", 
            Movies=new List<string>{"Friends (1994)","Bruce Almighty (2003)","Just Go with It (2011)"}
        }
    }, 
};
```

using c# in asp.net

Comment: Can you tag the programming language as well ?

Comment: it shows some generic class name in grid view on binding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set GridView DataDource to **Dictionary.Values** like below:

```
GridView1.DataSource = actors.Values;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

**EDIT :** And the markup may look like this (thanks julealgon for pointing to Movies List) :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ActorId" HeaderText="Actor Id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ActorName" HeaderText="Actor Name"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BirthDate" HeaderText="Birth Date"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BirthPlace" HeaderText="Birth Place"  />   
        <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Photo" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Photo") %>'  runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Movies" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" DataSource='<%#Eval("Movies") %>' runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>   
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Here's how it is displayed:
[image]

You can download the test project I have used to test your code [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6i8p65gmkp0UTc0emYydXFtQ2s/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: But in above code Movies list values are not printed in place of that value mentioned below is printed --   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] please provide the solution for that so that all the contents inside list is also binded in grid view

Comment: @Shiv That will depend on how you want the values to be shown. You could create a TemplateField in the grid for the Movies column, and put a Listbox inside it's ItemTemplate, setting the DataSource as the .Movies property of the model. For instance something like this `<asp:ListBox runat="server" Datasource='<%# Eval("Movies") %>' />` should work fine.

Comment: @Shiv Also, the image url is probably useless to you I assume? In that case, you can use an ImageField and set it's DataImageUrlField atribute to "Photo", like this: `<asp:ImageField runat="server" DataImageUrlField="Photo" />`. Keep in mind afzalulh probably used the `AutogenerateColumns` property on the Grid to create that basic layout. If your model is not comprised of simple fields only, like ints and strings, you will probably need to build your own columns or use something more flexible like [Dynamic Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee845452.aspx).

Comment: @julealgon - I did not notice that there is a movie list even after OP pointing to that! Poor me :-(

Comment: thanx a lot...the code is working perfectly fine....before i was using label for that thats why it was nt working but after using --  <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" DataSource='<%#Eval("Movies") %>' runat="server"></asp:ListBox> it worked...thanx again

Comment: I HAVE BEEN LOOKING FOR A SOLUTION LIKE THIS FOR FARRRR TO LOOOONNG